# How do I read only the 26th column from a textfile?

Tags: python, io

My .txt file looks thus:

```
 === Predictions on test data ===

 inst#     actual  predicted error prediction (6)
 1        1:1        6:6   +   0.753 (0)
 2        1:1        6:6   +   0.753 (0)
 3        1:1        5:5   +   0.975 (2)
 4        1:1        5:5   +   1 (11)
 5        1:1        5:5   +   0.992 (0)
 6        1:1        6:6   +   0.941 (0)
 7        1:1        3:3   +   0.857 (0)
 8        1:1        2:2   +   0.967 (0)
 9        1:1        2:2   +   1 (0)
10        1:1        5:5   +   1 (97)
11        1:1        5:5   +   0.956 (0)
12        1:1        5:5   +   1 (1)
13        1:1        5:5   +   0.958 (59)
14        1:1        5:5   +   0.969 (0)
15        1:1        5:5   +   0.984 (0)
16        1:1        4:4   +   0.8 (0)
17        1:1        5:5   +   1 (141)
18        1:1        5:5   +   0.974 (5)
```

How do I read only the first value from the "predicted" column ? particularly, the numeric values occur on the 26th column(say) in each line?

I wrote a python script :

```
f = open("out_grasp_R.txt", 'r')
f.readline()
f.readline()
f.readline()
for line in f:
     f.read(25)
     print(f.read(1))
     f.readline()
```

I get an error saying that "mixing iteration and read methods would lose data"

I want an array like:

```
[6,6,5,....]
```

What do I do ?

Comment: `for line in f: print(line[26])`? For an explanation of the error, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/22179974/3001761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simpler to split and get the first element from the third column

```
with open("out_grasp_R.txt", 'r') as f:  
    next(f)
    print([line.split()[2][0] for line in f])

['6', '6', '5', '5', '5', '6', '3', '2', '2', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '4', '5', '5']
```

If you are sure of the spacing use  `print([line[21] for line in f])` which corresponds to the data you want based on your input file. Unless you consider spaces columns you actually have six columns.

Answer (score 1):

Using `readlines` method, you get a list of strings for each line:

```
filename = 'out_grasp_R.txt'
with open(filename) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

predicted = []
for line in content:
    predicted.append(int(line.split()[2][0]))

print predicted

[6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 3, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the line string and index it just like an array.

```
print(line[25])
```

Or for making the array:

```
array.append(line[25])
```

This does require that you're certain it's *always* the 26th character in a line though.

Comment: I used this:  `data = np.append(data, line[25])`