# Reading data from non-CSV files

Tags: python, csv, file-io

I have data in a text file that looks like this:

```
2,20 12,40 13,100 14,300
15,440 16,10 24,50 25,350
26,2322 27,3323 28,9999 29,2152
30,2622 31,50
```

I would like to read this data into two different lists in Python. However, this is not a CSV file. The data is read like this: 
`mass1,intensity1 mass2,intensity2 mass3,intensity3...`

How should I go about reading the masses and intensities into two different lists? I am trying to avoid writing this file to make the data neater and/or in CSV format.

Comment: You can get a list of mass/intensity pairs with `split(" ")` then split each pair with `split(",")`.

Comment: Why should you "avoid writing this file to make the data neater" ?? That seems like good practice!

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you could `line.split()` each line to isolate the individual pairs, then use `pair.split(",")` to separate the mass and intensity in each pair.

Answer (score 1):

```
mass_results = []
intensity_results = []

with open('in.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for readings in line.split(' '):
            mass, intensity = readings.split(',')
            mass_results.append(int(mass.strip()))
            intensity_results.append(int(intensity.strip()))

print('Mass values:')
print(mass_results)
print('Intensity values:')
print(intensity_results)
```

Yields:

```
Mass values:
[2, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]
Intensity values:
[20, 40, 100, 300, 440, 10, 50, 350, 2322, 3323, 9999, 2152, 2622, 50]
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
?

Comment: You can read the entire file at once (i.e. `data=f.read()`), then use `data.split()` rather than reading line by line and splitting on spaces. Split without arguments splits based on whitespace. With this, I'd have `mass = [int(x.split(',')[0].strip()) for x in data.split()]` and `intensity = [int(x.split(',')[1].strip()) for x in data.split()]`

Comment: So I have to skip the first 25 lines of the file for I am using a for loop to skip them. However when I try @jkb method I am getting this error: ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data. Could you explain why?

Comment: To answer your first question: If you split your reading, say `2,3` you should get two values. Those individual values could be `strip()` stripped. However, if you have any malformed entries, like `2,3,4,5` then splitting them could screw up the script. If you are getting errors, try printing each or each reading, before splitting, to review what might be happening.

Comment: The data is exactly as I pasted it, I can't seem to find the error you may be referring to

Comment: Strange. Works fine for me, in Python 2.7 and 3.4. Are you sure your file is separated with spaces, and not tabs? Does your file have a newline at the end?

Comment: My file does have an extra line at the end, but even when I get rid of it I have the same error

Comment: Do you use reddit? If you PM me on reddit I can help you directly. Same username. I think it's a data issue...

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

# read the file
f = open('input.dat','r')
data = f.read()
f.close()

# grab mass and intensity values using regex
m_re = '[0-9]+(?=,[0-9]+)'
i_re = '(?<=[0-9],)[0-9]+'
mass = re.findall(m_re,data)
intensity = re.findall(i_re,data)

# view results
print "Mass values:", mass
print "Intensity values:", intensity
print "(Mass,Intensity):", zip(mass,intensity)
```

If the 25 line header that you mentioned has matches for the regex and alters the results, you could try replacing the file input section above with this:

```
# read the file
f = open('input.dat','r')
lines = f.readlines()[25:] # ignore first 25 lines
f.close()
data = ' '.join(lines)
```

Comment: hi jkb. :) do you know who it is?

Answer (score 0):

Assume the input file looks like

```
#this is header
#this is header
#this is header
2,20 12,40 13,100 14,300
15,440 16,10 24,50 25,350
26,2322 27,3323 28,9999 29,2152
30,2622 31,50
```

You could use `re`

### METHOD 1

If the file is really large

```
import re

def xy_parser( fname, header_len=3):
    with open( fname) as f:
        for i,line in enumerate(f):
            if i < header_len:
                continue
            else:
                yield re.findall( '[0-9]+,[0-9]+', line)

def xy_maker( xy_str):
    return map( float, xy_str.split(',') )

my_xys = []
for xys in xy_parse( 'xydata.txt'):
    my_xys += [ xy_maker(val) for val in xys  ]
my_xys 
#[[2.0, 20.0],
# [12.0, 40.0],
# [13.0, 100.0],
# [14.0, 300.0],
# [15.0, 440.0],
# [16.0, 10.0],
# [24.0, 50.0],
# [25.0, 350.0],
# [26.0, 2322.0],
# [27.0, 3323.0],
# [28.0, 9999.0],
# [29.0, 2152.0],
# [30.0, 2622.0],
# [31.0, 50.0]]
```

### METHOD 2

I also want to point out that if the file is not too large, then read it in one go

```
f = open('xydata.txt', 'r')
header_len = 3
for i in xrange(header_len): # skip the header lines
    f.readline()
data_str = f.read().replace('\n','') # read from current file pos to end of file and replace new line chars

data_xy_str = re.findall( '[0-9]+,[0-9]+', data_str)
my_xys      = [ xy_maker(xy_str) for xy_str in data_xy_str ]
# yields the same result as above
```

Comment: This is what I am doing to read in the data now: `with open(fname, 'r') as f: 
        for j in xrange(25):
            f.next()
        data = f.read()` However that is giving me the error: `ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data. ` Can't do anything else or test anything until I fix this.

Comment: That is because you are calling ```.read``` while the file object ```f``` is being treated like a generator. Try replacing ```data=f.read()``` with ```data = list(f)``` This will make data a list of lines. If instead you want the file data as a single string do ```data= ' '.join(f)```

Comment: Why does that work? What is list and what is a generator? Sorry I'm pretty new to this stuff and just trying to understand it. Thanks for being so helpful

Comment: Iterators and generators: http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html

Comment: Why you received a value error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179974/mixing-file-readline-and-file-next  (see the selected answer)

Comment: the ```list``` function makes a python list from an iterator (it's arg)