# Can read() and readline() be used together?

Tags: python

Is it possible to use both read() and readline() on one text file in python?

When I did that, it will only do the first reading function.

```
file = open(name, "r")
inside = file.readline()
inside2 = file.read()

print(name)
print(inside)
print(inside2)
```

The result shows only the `inside` variable, not `inside2`.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179974/mixing-file-readline-and-file-next)

Comment: [Related](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Your code seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Note that by first doing `readline`, the call to `read` is not getting the first line of the file. So if your file only has one line in it, you'll not see anything print from that.

Comment: @B.Eckles i'm using python 3.5.2

Comment: @JoanLamrack Got it. Did you see my other comment (and the two subsequent answers people posted below)? Did they explain it?

Comment: A pedantic wording point, you're not using them "simultaneously", you're using them "in succession", an important difference

Comment: @B.Eckles yes, i read both of them, and now i understand what to do with explanation using book analogy and the seek() function  :))

Answer (score 6):

Reading a file is like reading a book.  When you say `.read()`, it reads through the book until the end.  If you say `.read()` again, well you forgot one step.  You can't read it again unless you flip back the pages until you're at the beginning.  If you say `.readline()`, we can call that a page.  It tells you the contents of the page and then turns the page.  Now, saying `.read()` starts there and reads to the end.  That first page isn't included.  If you want to start at the beginning, you need to turn back the page.  The way to do that is with the `.seek()` method.  It is given a single argument: a character position to seek to:

```
with open(name, 'r') as file:
    inside = file.readline()
    file.seek(0)
    inside2 = file.read()
```

There is also another way to read information from the file.  It is used under the hood when you use a `for` loop:

```
with open(name) as file:
    for line in file:
        ...
```

That way is `next(file)`, which gives you the next line.  This way is a little special, though.  If `file.readline()` or `file.read()` comes after `next(file)`, you will get an error that mixing iteration and read methods would lose data.  (Credits to Sven Marnach for pointing this out.)

Comment: Note, however, that in Python 2 you can't mix `next(file)` and `file.readline()`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Oh, I didn't know that. What happens if you do?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: That's undefined.  `next()` uses a separate buffer, and `readline()` doesn't see that buffer.  So when using `f.readline()` after `next(f)`, you will probably skip some portion of the file.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: An interesting note.  I didn't know of that myself, but it is now added to the answer.

Comment: @SvenMarnach That sounds interesting. I think it would be interesting if you did a self-answered question on that behavior.

Comment: Made sense! i added the file.seek(0) and it works just the way i wanted it

Comment: @MosesKoledoye It's documented behaviour, and there is http://stackoverflow.com/q/22179974/279627

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

`file.readline()` reads a line from the file (the first line in this case), and then `file.read()` reads the rest of the file starting from the *seek* position, in this case, where `file.readline()` left off.

You are receiving an empty string with `f.read()` probably because you reached *EOF* - End of File immediately after reading the first line with `file.readline()` implying your file only contains one line.

You can however return to the start of the file by moving the seek position to the start with `f.seek(0)`.

Comment: This gives me an initial understanding about both function. thanks!